# How can I restrict the use of commands to only someone without a certain role on discordjs?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have my bot in a discord server with quite a few troublemakers and I would like to be able to ban the use of commands for certain users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take away their roles, or just mute them.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
if (!message.author.hasPermission(“BAN_MEMBERS”) {
  message.channel.send(“You don’t have permission to use this”)
}

//The rest of your code`
```